# Css margin from the center

Tags: html, css, margin, center

There is **margin-left**, **margin-right**, **margin-top** and **margin-bottom**. But is there also a margin where you can margin from the center of the page ?

[image]

Imagine I want to build everything from the center with the help of angles or something like that:D Is that possible ?

Comment: If you want to center everything use margin: 0 auto;

Comment: uhm.. that's not how you're supposed to build your page..

Comment: trying to imagine .. :D ..

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` ?

Comment: Margin is doing what you are describing it kicks off the elements edges to the sides. If you want the opposite make a big element and add padding to it. or did i miss the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if only using the features and functions of CSS, it is impossible.

HTML rendering process is like:

1. draw some horizontal lines to divide the top-down areas.
2. put some boxes into each area by floating left or right.
3. with some other special controls like relative position ...

If you really want to do that, you need to use JavaScript to handle it manually. You need to control the absolute positions for all the elements, calculate and reset them when some elements changed.

Comment: Well okay :D if that is true, it is all I wanted to know. But it had been pretty cool to control everything from the center of the page and not the sides - with css and html because I like never worked with javascript :P

Comment: haha, maybe it is a good idea, you can send mails to those big companies and organizations and ask them to support this feature in CSS4